# Flex_await_healthy Error while deployment on google app engine flex environment

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, gcloud, app.yaml

It takes too long to update default service and then after waiting for like 10 mins, Getting the following **error**, while deploying my app.yaml on Google app engine.

"error": {
"code": 9,
"message": "An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2023-11-30T12:58:15.855Z147479.jc.2: "
}

**app.yaml**

`runtime: custom`

`env: flex`

`entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 main:app`

resources:
cpu: 4
memory_gb: 4
disk_size_gb: 100

manual_scaling:
instances: 2

Tried with auto scaling as well, but the error remains the same. Tried adding readiness_check as well, but no success.. tried redeploying as well, no success

Also tried updating gcloud sdk, but no success either.

Comment: Please check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/troubleshooting#errors_when_deploying_to_an_existing_flexible_environment_version).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RobertG.

I did tried this, but no success.

I tried deleting my images from GCR as well and re-deploying fresh versions, but still the same error

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this [error](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/troubleshooting#errors_when_deploying_to_an_existing_flexible_environment_version) because you are updating an unhealthy deployment with a working docker image. You mentioned that you already deleted and re-deployed your images in GCR. **Container Registry** is already **[deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/deprecations/container-registry-deprecation)**. I suggest that you [transition to Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr) as it is the recommended container storage and management in Google Cloud.